# Writing lambda expressions in terms of pure functions

Tags: function-construction, pure-function

I am trying to create some functions that I want to comfortably compose together using the pure functions.

The functions were originally written in $\lambda$-expressions so I would like to keep the format as close to it as possible. They are

- ${\rm id}:=(\lambda x . x)$
- ${\rm almost\$factorial}:=(\lambda f.(\lambda n. \text{If } (n=0) \text{ then } 1 \text{ else } n*f(n-1)))$
- ${\rm factorial0}:= {\rm almost\$factorial} ({\rm id})$

I realized that I can write

```
id:= (#)&
```

for ${\rm id}$.

So `id[x]` gives me `x`, which is what I expected. However, I'm at lost on how to write $almost-factorial$. I tried

```
almost$factorial := If[#1==0, 1, #1*(#2[#1 - 1])]&
```

But it only works when it takes two arguments at once. I would to be able to define `almost$factorial` as a pure function that takes only one argument and outputs another pure function, which I can apply.

```
almost$factorial[id] [0] = 1.
```

Is this possible to do in Mathematica?

Comment: Mma also has the `Identity` function, so you can also do `id=Identity`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are two ways. First with pure functions:

```
idP = Function[x, x];
almostFactorialP = Function[f, Function[n, If[n == 0, 1, n*f[n - 1]]]]

almostFactorialP[idP][4]
(* 12 *)
```

In general, this is the same method you tried with the `Slot` (`#`) notation. Unfortunately, in a construct like `(#+(#+#&))&` there is no way to refer to the outer `#` in the inner function or fill the inner slots. This is the reason I used `Function` explicitly.

Another way is to use `SubValues`:

```
id[x_] := x;
almostFactorial[f_][n_] := If[n == 0, 1, n*f[n - 1]];

almostFactorial[id][4]
(* 12 *)
```

Comment: Thank you. The first one is the one I needed and it felt the most similar to the lambda expressions given. I'm guessing it's not doable with the # shortcuts mentioned in my post?

Comment: @BeerR When you try it in the shorter `#` form, you will get into trouble as you cannot distinguish which `#` refers to your outer lambda expression. This is why you have to use the longer, named-argument version.

Comment: +1 Just for fun: `almostFactorialNoWay = #0[[0]][If[#2[1]==0, 1, #2[1] * #[#2[1] - 1]]]&[#, Slot]&`.  Although we might as well switch to full-on Church-coded lambda calculus once we start going down that path ;D

Comment: @WReach Hehe.. yes. I was unwilling to go that path of the devil :)